# Using swap! instead of reset! in atom - clojure

Tags: clojure

Given I have this action to perform

```
(def structure (atom [{:id "an-id"} {:id "another-id"}]))
(def job {:type "some-job"})

(reset! structure (map #(if (= "an-id" (:id %)) (update-in % [:performed-jobs] (fnil conj []) job) %) @structure))

next structure:
[{:id "an-id" :performed-jobs [{:type "some-job"}]} {:id "another-id"}]
```

How can I use swap! to change a single occurrence in my structure instead of resetting it all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `reset!` by `swap!` by giving it a function that takes the old value of the `atom` and returns a new value to store in the `atom`.
2. Replace dereferencing of the `atom` with the function's argument, the old value.

   ```
   (swap! structure
     (fn [old]
       (map #(if (= "an-id" (:id %))
               (update-in % [:performed-jobs]
                          (fnil conj []) job) %)
             old)))
   ```

Comment: It works! But I was thinking about avoiding map, because I'm sure the id is unique, so I don't have to map the entire structure. Maybe using assoc, but it's not going to be trivial work with positions in this vector.

Comment: This is usually how it's done in Clojure, but you can make an optimized version with reduce where you terminate early or use something like Specter.

Comment: @madam As I commented on your last similar question, you have your data set up so any operations on them will necessarily be `O(n)`. Even if you use `reduce` with an early exit, you're likely to get better performance, but it will still be a linear complexity (you may always need to iterate every element). If you find yourself always needing to find/manipulate stuff in maps in a seq, you should try to set up your data differently so you don't need to iterate the entire sequence every time.